# How do you call or use import statements in Firebase Version 9 in React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to create an App in React Native, but every time I run my code I get an error saying my import statements are incorrect.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Input } from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';

const auth = getAuth();
const SignUpScreen = (navigation) => {

const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('')
const [validationMessage, setValidationMessage] = useState('')

let validateAndSet = (value, valueToCompare, setValue) => {
    value !== valueToCompare ?setValidationMessage('The password does not match') 
    : setValidationMessage('')
    setValue(value)
}

    async function createAccount(){
        email === '' || password === ''
        ?setValidationMessage('Required field is missing information')
        : ''

        try {
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
            navigation.navigate('Log In')
        } catch (error) {
            setValidationMessage(error.message)
        }
    }
```

However, once I change my import statements by adding compat, I get an error saying "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly.

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/compat/auth';
```

Comment: Show us what error you get. You should just import from `'@firebase/**'` or `'firebase/**'` or `@firebase/**/lite` or `'firebase/**/lite'`. Lite end is for servers/ssr.

Answer (score 0):

Your import is:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/compat/auth';
```

This is incorrect, as you're trying to import the modular function names from the `compat` path.

To use the modular API, import from the non-compact, default path:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
```